# Inserting PHP variables AND an array into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a form that includes a multiple select box. As a result, I am inserting variables into the database (e.g. the contents of input fields) as well as an array - the multiple select box values.

I tried to do this as two separate queries, but I'm getting an error after my first query:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Here's my code snippet (the first query) with by debugging commented out:

```
$instruments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['instruments']);
//var_dump($_POST['instruments']);

$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($instruments));
//var_dump($columns);

$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($instruments));
//var_dump($escaped_values);

$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
//var_dump($values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `depfinder_sandbox`(instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5) VALUES ($values)";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

While debugging, I've found the following:

- `var_dump($instruments)` returns NULL despite the variable being set.
- However, `var_dump($_POST['instruments'])` returns as it should.
- If I use `$_POST['instruments']`, `var_dump($escaped_values)` returns `string(4) "0, 1"`, which is incorrect.
- `var_dump($values)` returns NULL whatever I do.

Even if the variables were returning as expected, would I still have a column count problem given that `$instruments[]` can contain anything from 1 to 5 values, yet the query stipulates 5 (instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5)?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I have now:

```
foreach ($_POST['instruments'] as $key => $value)
{ 
    $instruments[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
}

var_dump($instruments); // returns perfectly

$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($instruments));
var_dump($columns); // returns: string(4) "0, 1"

$values  = implode(", ", $columns);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `depfinder_sandbox`(instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5) VALUES ($values)";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); // returns: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: Strip the column names from your query and use default values in the table definition? It will then insert as many as you have and use defaults for the rest?

Comment: **1)** The second parameter for `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes string, you seem to be passing an array. **2)** You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Also what @ICanHasKittenz said :)

Comment: @Fluffeh could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz 1) fixed :) 2) are you talking about line 1? If so, would it be better to loop through there and assign variables to each array value? If I define the variable like I have, it outputs fine with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Sebastian Once you loop through the `mysqli_real_escape..` function, you have all your escaped values. Get the column names like you have done above from POST (imploded). Display the columns in the INSERT query and implode the escaped values into the query.

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz see my update. Is that what you meant? I'm getting the errors that you see commented.

Comment: @Sebastian Could you paste a sample output of `$_POST['instruments']`? That should clear most things.

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz do you mean a `vardump`? An example would be: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Piano" [1]=> string(7) "Piccolo" [2]=> string(8) "Trombone" }`

Comment: @Sebastian Ah, I thought you got your columns from the POST too. So how do you match them up with your values? Is it like if there are 3 values start saving from left-most column - _instrument1, 2 & 3_? If so, you could build an array of column names and depending of the number of values use [array_slice](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to fetch the column names and implode within the INSERT.

Comment: Yes, the columns do come from the POST. The form allows between 1 and 5 instruments to be selected, so the number is not fixed. This comes into PHP as an array which I loop to add `mysqli_real_escape_string` to each one. I then implode them to make them a string and try to add them to the database via INSERT. Does that make sense?